# Shinydashboard: make the sidebar open over the body instead of squeezing the main body

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Instead of having the sidebar open and squeeze the body, I would like the sidebar to open by going over the body so it does not mess up the size of my output.
How could I achieve that if even possible?

Current behavior:

[image: From]

Desired behavior:

[image: To:]

Code used on the example:

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Very hard to say without seeing the code. Have you tried taking the sidebar out of the normal document flow with position absolute or something, and using z-index?

Comment: @victorbergstroem I added the code, but there is no html/css involved so you can't control those thing by default

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated code and see if it meets your needs. From my viewpoint at least having the sidebar open over the chart looks not too great.  Why not open your app without the sidebar being present?

```
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(shinyjs)

    ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
 dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
  menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
   )
 ),
 dashboardBody(
useShinyjs(),
tabItems(
  # First tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
          fluidRow(
            box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

            box(
              title = "Controls",
              sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
            )
          )
  ),

  # Second tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
          h2("Widgets tab content")
  )
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

 addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")


 set.seed(122)
 histdata <- rnorm(500)

 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
hist(data)
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: My app already close the sidebar by default. 
The reason I want it to go over the body, is that is have complex output that get messed up everytime I open the sidebar